# Restored database smaller than the backup file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

The new database created from a restore file is half the size of the backup file I restored from. Why?

*Original backup settings:*
Recovery Model: SIMPLE
Backup Type: FULL

Comment: How did you restore as in the TSQL you used or the options you selected from SSMS GUI?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question.  Such as what statement did you use to do the restore.  Where did the backup come from?  What was the size of the backup file?  What is the size of the files?  What does `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\x\x.bak1;` say the size of the database is?  Is there more than one database in the .bak file?

Comment: Probably your .BAK file contains more than one backup, which is possible if you constantly write to the same file *without* using WITH INIT. Just a guess though; your question doesn't include enough details to be sure.

Comment: This is less probable than scenario of multiple backup sets in the media, but was the database property for AutoShrink enabled and the DB possisbly shrank during an idle condition after the recovery?

Answer (score 2):

It is very rare a backup size would be larger than size of database.A full backup contains the entire database's data files that are used , and the active portion of the transaction log during the backup.  It is thus possible that the backup file is significantly smaller than the database size, but being on larger side is rare though.

The reason for the large backup file from what we have seen is, because the file contains multiple backup sets.  A backup file will contain multiple backup sets if you repeatedly back up to the same file, without using the INIT or FORMAT options.

Also, if you go and check in SQL server management Studio there is an option to Append or Overwrite all existing backup sets. If you have selected  Append option, it will add the backup to the same .bak file and the .bak file will be larger for every backup and hence you see a larger backup file.

Moreover, try to run the below query and post results which will give us the backup details and will confirm on the backup files status:

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(128)
SET @DBName = 'YourDBNameHere'

Select a.database_name,a.backup_start_date
        ,BackupPath = b.physical_device_name
        ,BackupSizeMB = a.backup_size/1024/1024 
        ,CompressedBackMB = a.compressed_backup_size/1024/1024
    From msdb.dbo.backupset a
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily b
            ON a.media_set_id = b.media_set_id
    Where a.type = 'D'
        And a.backup_start_date > GETDATE()-7
        And b.physical_device_name not like '{%'
        AND a.database_name = @DBName
    Order By a.database_name,a.backup_start_date
```